# How to display Russian characters exporting from php to tab separated (as if excel) file

Tags: php, excel, encoding, export

Here is simple code to export php to excel

```
$filename ="excelreport.xls";
$contents = "русский \t testdata2 \t testdata3 \t \n";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo $contents;
```

There is `русский` but in excel it displays as `ļ»æŃ€ŃŃŃŠŗŠøŠ¹`

Searching have found information that Excel does not recognize UTF-8. Found several ways as if solution, but none works

Tried `echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";` (no changes)

then `$contents = mb_convert_encoding($contents, "SJIS","UTF-8");` in excel get `„‚„…„„„{„y„z`

then `$contents = mb_convert_encoding($contents, "UTF8", "JIS, eucjp-win, sjis-win");` in excel get `Ń€ŃŃŃŠŗŠøŠ¹`

This php-excel class http://code.google.com/p/php-excel/source/browse/branches/class-excel-xml.inc.php?r=9 that correctly displays Russian characters, but which part of code does it...? php-excel class do not use because need simple code which I can understand and modify.

Tried this `echo chr(255).chr(254).iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE//IGNORE", $contents);` something better. But first excel line is ok `русский     testdata2   testdata3`
 but the second what is this `胑菑臑臑뫐룐말ठ琠獥摴瑡㉡ठ琠獥摴瑡㍡ठਠ` and how to avoid it...

**Solution**
Oh very simple solution at least for me

```
$filename ="excelreport.xls";
$contents = "русский \t testdata2 \t testdata3 \t \n";
header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
echo chr(255).chr(254).iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE//IGNORE", $contents);
```

Only question. If people offer so many different ways how to get solution and not all are working, does it means that depending on user computer configuration (for example Regional settings) one solution may work and other not?

Comment: It is not an xls file, it is a tab separated file, that you are returning to client.

Comment: I can open it as excel. OK, I will modify question heading

Comment: You are using a pretty weird file format. Why don't you want to save it in csv? In my Excel 2003 your file is opened incorrectly without splitting the content by cells.

Comment: Yes, I changed to `$filename ="excelreport.csv";
header('Content-type: application/csv');`